# how to get the most common occur with unix utilites

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

following block of code is saved in file INP.txt:

```
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
lol.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/face/|
wtf.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/twitter/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
omg.txt|/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/|
```

i have, for example, this input file (which is saved in variable) , my task is to find the most common file at given path.

**e.g. Find most common file in path /Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/**

expected output: 
    `omg.txt`

I spent hours to find the best solution - unsuccessfully.

p.s. sorry for my bad english, i hope you understand my problem

**edit:**
multiple files occur the same number of times -> get whichever file of files having same number of occurrence

i have discovered another problem, my script **can't create any temp files (like e.g. `sed -i` does)**...is it OK with awk?

Comment: If you already tried it yourself, you should [edit] the question and show your attempt. Also include the desired result for the example you have shown..

Comment: @EdMorton sorry for for misunderstanding. I'm not very good at bash. I just know e.g. `sed -i` creates some temp files. i have to use utility which doesn't create it...im gonna edit question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v tgt="/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/" '
    $2==tgt { max=(++cnt[$1] > max ? cnt[$1] : max) }
    END { for (file in cnt) if (cnt[file]==max) { print file; exit } }
' file
omg.txt
```

but without you showing us the expected output it's just a guess.

Comment: nice job, it works!...just one little problem, if there is same ocurrence of more files, output should be only one of them (does't matter which of them)

Comment: I updated it to`exit`after printing the first matching file. A `break` would've produced the same output.

Comment: A slightly different version `awk -F'|' -v tgt="/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/" '$2==tgt&&a[$1]++{a[$1]>max&&max=a[$1]&&big=$1}END{print big}'`

Comment: @EdMorton  i just realized this: if the file in folder is deleted over time, record of opening stays in Input file. but it will printout the name of last modified files which exists..any ideas?

Comment: Sorry  I don't understand how any of what you said in your comment is related to your question. I suspect there's something you know about the meaning of the fields in your input file that you haven't told us yet. Sounds like you need to post a new question with sample input/output that demonstrates your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'|' '$2=="/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/" {print $1}' input.txt |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
  3 omg.txt
  2 wtf.txt
  1 lol.txt
```

Comment: sorry, does't work for me, my variable input name is INP,  `awk -F'|' '$2=="/Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/" {print $1}' $INP |
  sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` ...i tried this, still doesn't work

Comment: awk expects a file name. If you want to parse a variable try `echo "$INP" | awk ...`.

Answer (score 0):

A different technique: a pipeline of tools:

```
popular() {
    grep -F "|$1|" "$2" | cut -d'|' -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed -n '$s/ \+[0-9]\+ //p'
}
popular /Users/jaro/documents/inc/linked/ INP.txt
```

Breaking up that one-liner

```
popular() {
    grep -F "|$1|" "$2"        |  # find the lines you're searching for
    cut -d'|' -f1              |  # extract only the first field
    sort | uniq -c             |  # aggregate them
    sort -n                    |  # sort numerically
    sed -n '$s/ \+[0-9]\+ //p'    # and remove the count
}
```

Comment: consider it picked. Note that, for GNU grep anyway, egrep and fgrep are deprecated in favour of `grep -E` and `grep -F`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a AWK version avoiding any explicit loop:

```
awk -F '|' '
    $2 == "'$1'" {
        if (++count[$1] > max) {
            max = count[$1];
            fname = $1
        }
    }
    END { print fname }
' "$2"
```